# Is there a way to view the undo stack?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, undo

I'm learning about undo, and I'd like a way to peek into the undo objects (`NSInvocation`s) in the `undoManager` so I can see what's going on. I couldn't see anything like this in the docs, but maybe someone knows a way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
class-dump -C NSUndo /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
```

to find out about the inner structure of the undo related classes. You will find that
the NSUndoManager has two instance variables named _undoStack and _redoStack. It's pretty obvious how it's structured, so you can write a little method printing the stack. I found that quite handy for debugging undo related problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For anyone (like me) who is wondering what class-dump is, I found it here: http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Core Data? Core Data provides automatic undo/redo support. Otherwise, the `NSUndoManager` will have an empty stack.

I suppose my question to you would be, why do you want to look at the stack? In practice, there's really no reason you should have to look at the undo manager's stack. If you're looking for advice on how to create undo actions and push them on the stack, here's a [pretty good overview](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSUndoManager) on how to do that. [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/RegisteringUndo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000206) on the subject is also quite good. I'm especially fond of the invocation-based method.

Comment: I'm going through "Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X" which has a chapter on using undo. It's not using Core Data (yet).
The reason I want to look at the stack is just to know how things are working so I can understand it better. I want to check that what's actually going on matches what I think is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can print your undo manager's `_undoStack` private property:

```swift
let undoStack = object_getIvar(undoManager, class_getInstanceVariable(UndoManager.self, "_undoStack")!)

print(undostack.debugDescription)
```

Based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/MattyAyOh/71b640cf88cc4e059927).